# real quadratic number fields with cyclic Hilbert 2-class field of order greater than or equal to 16

Tags: number-theory

How can one demonstrate that there exists real quadratic number fields with cyclic Hilbert 2-class field of order greater than or equal to 16?

I believe this is the case, and it can easily be demonstrated when the 2-class group has rank 2, by factoring the discriminant into prime fundamental discriminants, but I don't see how to show this when the 2-class group is cyclic.

Comment: What do you mean by "it can easily be demonstrated *when*..."? The statement is an existence statement, so I'm not sure what you mean by "when". Also what is the $2$-class group?

Comment: Yes--I should have been more careful in my wording.  The 2-class group is the 2-Sylow subgroup of the class group of the algebraic integers of an algebraic number field, and is isomorphic to the Hilbert 2-class field (subfield of the Hilbert class field that has order maximum power of 2).  This is all algebraic number theory stuff, and what I meant by my "when" statement is that if the 2-class group of the field has rank 2, then it is well known how to obtain the Hilbert 2-class field with 4-rank 2, so one could obtain the order 16 or greater.  But the cyclic case is not at all clear to me.

Comment: By the theory of genus fields, it is easy to obtain arbitrarily large $2$-torsion in the ideal class group of a quadratic field. But off the top of my head, I don't know of any method that would produce a field verifying your criterion. Have you looked in tables of class groups of quadratic fields? Where is this question from?

Comment: It's from a 2010 paper by Mouhib entitled "Infinite Hilbert 2-Class Field Tower of Quadratic Number Fields" in Acta Arithmetica (Propositon 3.3).  And yes I know it is easy to obtain arbitrarily large 2-torsion if you let the 2-rank of the class group increase, but it's the cyclic case that puzzles me.  I haven't checked tables of class groups of quadratic fields--perhaps you can refer me to a website or resource that would be helpful here?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have anything specific in mind, but these groups have certainly been compiled up to very large discriminant, and you can also compute them using SAGE. A quick google search turns up [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195513096), for instance. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Bruno--this looks like a very good paper for me to check out, which I will do, and hopefully give me the field I am looking for.  And please see my Legendere symbol question response to you as well.